# Matching and Updating a column in R data table

Tags: r, data.table, match

I have 2 data tables. The dput and data tables are given below:

dt1

```
       email          custtype
1:   abc@yahoo.com     subs
2:   eli@gmail.com     subs
3: tod@hotmail.com     subs

dt1 = setDT(structure(list(email = c("abc@yahoo.com", "eli@gmail.com", "tod@hotmail.com"
), custtype = c("subs", "subs", "subs")), .Names = c("email", 
"custtype"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)))
```

dt2

```
      emails         range
1:    sam@live.com  orange
2: tod@hotmail.com  orange
3:    ver@live.com  orange
4:   yahoo@yah.com  orange

dt2 = setDT(structure(list(emails = structure(1:4, .Label = c("sam@live.com", 
"tod@hotmail.com", "ver@live.com", "yahoo@yah.com"), class = "factor"), 
    range = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "orange", class = "factor")), .Names = c("emails", 
"range"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L)))
```

I am trying to match the email from dt1 to emails in dt2 and then trying to update the custtype column in dt1. So far I have tried

```
dt1[match(email,dt2$emails), custtype:="some value"]
```

What this does is that it changes the value at the index where the match was found instead of changing it against the email address for which a match was found.

The resulting data table should look like below. The email for which a match was found, the corresponding custtype should be upated with a value provided:

```
  email             custtype
1:   abc@yahoo.com     subs
2:   eli@gmail.com     subs
3: tod@hotmail.com     some value
```

Comment: This is a very common use of the package and one of the main reasons I use it. The vignettes don't yet have a chapter covering this but are essential reading to learn the package: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started In the meantime, this usage is covered in the user-written "Docs" on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/data.table/4976/joins-and-merges/17560/update-values-in-a-join#t=201610102031286494036

Comment: I'm still a data.table newbie, but `dt2[dt1, on = c("emails"="email")][,`:=`(custtype = dplyr::coalesce(as.character(range), custtype), range=NULL)][]` came to my mind.

Comment: @lukeA Fyi, `:=` will only modify `dt2` if it's done within the first `[]`.

Comment: @Frank You mean it's the same as `dt2[dt1, on = c("emails"="email")][,.(emails, custtype = dplyr::coalesce(as.character(range), custtype))]`?

Comment: @lukeA Yeah, I think so.

Answer (score 5):

You tried :

```
dt1[match(email,dt2$emails), custtype:="some value"]
```

What that `match()` did was find row numbers of `dt2` which you then passed in as an index to `dt1`. Which doesn't make any sense.

The idea is you use `dt2` directly to index `dt1`.

```
> dt1
             email custtype
1:   abc@yahoo.com     subs
2:   eli@gmail.com     subs
3: tod@hotmail.com     subs

> dt1[dt2, on=c(email="emails"), custtype:="some value"]

> dt1
             email   custtype
1:   abc@yahoo.com       subs
2:   eli@gmail.com       subs
3: tod@hotmail.com some value
```

That seems to be the result you wrote you wanted.

[FAQ 2.14](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-faq.html#can-you-explain-further-why-data.table-is-inspired-by-ab-syntax-in-base) explains the thinking behind `A[B]` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` approach is by joining the two tables:

```
dt2[dt1, on = c(emails = "email"), mult = "first"][!is.na(range), custtype := "some value"][, range := NULL][]
```

### Explanation

#### Join

```
dt2[dt1, on = c(emails = "email"), mult = "first"]
```

is a right join which returns all rows of `dt1`:

```
            emails  range custtype
1:   abc@yahoo.com     NA     subs
2:   eli@gmail.com     NA     subs
3: tod@hotmail.com orange     subs
```

`mult = "first"` prevents unwanted duplicates in case there are multiple entries in `dt2` with the same email address but different values of `range`.

#### Change `custtype`

Only matching email addresses will have a non-NA entry in the `range` column.

```
[!is.na(range), custtype := "some value"]
```

uses this to change `custtype` only in those rows where a match has been found.

#### Remove `range` column

The `range` column isn't needed anymore. It is removed by

```
[, range := NULL]
```

#### Print

As the last operation was an update *by reference* the final

```
[]
```

ensures the result gets printed.

Comment: What if there are multiple values for range for the same email. Meaning more than one row for the same email but with different range?

Comment: Good point. By default, `data.table` joins imply the parameter `mult = "all"` which could lead to unwanted duplicated entries. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using which. But still looking for a more elegant solution.

```
dt1[which(match(email, dt2$emails) > 0), custtype := "some value"]
```